# Evaluate parameters in curl API call

Tags: linux, shell

I got a curl that had to be rewritten recently, looking like this:

```
cmd=$("curl https://exampleurl/query -sX POST -H Authorization: Bearer $ingestToken   -H Content-Type: application/json -H Accept: application/json -H Accept-Charset: utf-8  -d {\"queryString\":\"$query\", \"start\": \"$start_time\", \"end\": \"$stop_time
```

This returns the error "No such file or directory"

I got a working version using eval $cmd, and I have compared the two curl strings generated by each method, and they look the same. Any ideas what is causing the error in this case?

Comment: The reason to use `\"` in your JSON is to escape quotes inside a double-quoted string. Try the following `"{\"queryString\": ...}"`. You definitely should *not* need to use `eval` for any of this. Ideally, you should use `jq` to generate the JSON, to ensure that the contents of the parameters are escaped as necessary.

Comment: Why are you using quotes around the command? Just use `$(curl https://...)`.